# Installing jvm apps

Tags: java

Given a java application that we would like to make available to the system path. Are there any best practices that should be observed when setting up jvm applications?

Currently I can only think of creating a simple shell script, executing `java -jar /path/to/jar/app.jar` and putting that in somewhere such as `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: What you have sounds fine.

Answer (score 1):

I will put /path/jar/app.jar in /usr/local/lib/appname/app.jar and in /usr/local/bin/ a shell script doing the job.

Comment: isn't /usr/{lib,bin} associated with binaries managed by a package manager? Currently I install source in /opt/ & link to /usr/local/bin via simple shell script. I was wondering if there is an established method that I may have missed?

Comment: In fact you right i think its better in /usr/local/bin, i edited the post.